# Can you render text from an SVG on a Google Map?

Tags: svg, google-maps-api-3, geojson, wkt

I'm in the process of building a Google Map that parses an SVG and transforms the paths into respective data layers. One of the issues I've run into is rendering the road names, since the SVG displays future roads.

My current process requires the text be converted to outlines and then the paths are converted to Well-Known Text which is then converted to GeoJSON. However two issues with this are the text comes out horribly distorted and any characters with holes in them (e.g. A and B) are completely filled in as it's just tracing the outline to create a polygon.

Below is a segment of the SVG and rendered map respectively:

[image]
[image]

The worst-case solution to the missing holes would be to create sub-groups for each character with paths describing the empty areas so that they can be appended to the geometry array. This would be a very tedious task and something I doubt can be automated.

I have no idea what's causing the distortion, but I suspect the parser just isn't reading the SVG coordinates properly.

This is an example of one of the text paths:

```
<path class="cls-11" d="M897.42,943.78l0-.79.7-.25,0-1.14-.72-.2,0-.78,3.24,1.06,0,.85Zm1.23-1.22,1.06-.38a1.4,1.4,0,0,1,.29-.06v0a1.25,1.25,0,0,1-.28,0l-1.09-.31Z"/>
```

I'm using [SVG-to-WKT](https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt) and [Terraformer](http://terraformer.io/wkt-parser/) plus a little janky maths to convert the SVG to GeoJSON. That process has yielded acceptable results, besides the fact that it isn't compensating for mercator projection.

Any thoughts as to how I might be able to achieve the desired result?